# Meteor: Collection not defined in publish

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've got a fairly simple Meteor app with:

lib/collections.js

`var Meetings = new Meteor.Collection('meetings');`

and server/publications.js:

```
Meteor.publish("meetings", function () {
  return Meetings.find({"participants":this.userId});
});
```

This *was* working, I think, but now sometimes I get:

```
Exception from sub vvpqwiujATG49puAc ReferenceError: Meetings is not defined
at [object Object]._handler (app/server/publications.js:2:10)
```

I feel like this is an order of operations problem but my understanding is that lib/ should always run first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll award you partial credit for getting the collection defined under `lib` so it will be loaded before the publisher, however in order for the `Meetings` variable to be visible between files it will need to be declared globally. Remove the `var` before `Meetings` and you should be all set.